# Running javascript e2e tests on a local appium server

Tags: javascript, android, testing, mocha.js, appium

I'm wanting to run e2e tests written in javascript with mocha on an Appium server instance running a local android emulator. The app on test is an apk originally written in react-native.

On Windows I have the server up and running  with an Android Studio emulator through using the Appium desktop app. The server all looks good and has the apk of the native app I want to test working fine. I also have a basic describe/assert test written in mocha that I want to apply to the app.

My question is what do I need to include (presumably in the test file) to make the tests actually test the emulator application? I'm finding the documentation pretty confusing and the sample code seems pretty specific to a different use case.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: what documents are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the stuff on appium.io and their sample code on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 2 good js client libraries to use for Appium based project: [webdriverio](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/appium) and [wd](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/node). Personally, I'm using the second one so I can advice you how write tests with it and mocha:
my test file looks like this:

```
'use strict'

require(path.resolve('hooks', 'hooks'))

describe('Suite name', function () {
  before('Start new auction', async function () {
    //do before all the tests in this file, e.g. generate test data
  })

  after('Cancel auction', async function () {
    //do after all the tests in this file, e.g. remove test data
  })

 it('test1', async () => {
  // test steps and checks are here
 })

 it('test2', async () => {
  // test steps and checks are here
 })

 it('test3', async () => {
  // test steps and checks are here
 })
})
```

where *hooks.js* contains global before/after for all the tests:

```
const hooks = {}

before(async () => {
  // before all the tests, e.g. start Appium session
})

after(async () => {
  // after all the tests, e.g. close session
})

beforeEach(async () => {
  // before each test, e.g. restart app
})

afterEach(async function () {
  // e.g. take screenshot if test failed
})

module.exports = hooks
```

I'm not saying its the best practice of designing tests, but its one of multiple ways.

Comment: and how do you actually point these tests at the local server hosting the emulated app?

Comment: start the appium server from command line, and in js code create session on exports.local = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4723
}, if you connected emulator and do not specify platformVersion in capabilities, Appium will use it as default one

Answer (score 0):

Cool so I managed to get it working to a degree. I was checking through the Appium console logs as I was trying to run stuff and noticed that the session id was missing from my requests. All that was needed was to attach the driver using the session id. My code looks a bit like this:

```
"use strict";

var wd = require("wd")
var assert = require("assert")

var serverConfig = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 4723,
}

var driver = wd.remote(serverConfig)

driver.attach("0864a299-dd7a-4b2d-b3a0-e66226817761", function() {
    it("should be true", function() {
        const action = new wd.TouchAction()
        action
            .press({x: 210, y: 130})
            .wait(3000)
            .release()
        driver.performTouchAction(action)
        assert.equal(true, true)
    })
})
```

The equals true assert is just there as a placeholder sanity check. The only problem with this currently is that I'm copy-pasting the alpha-numeric session id inside the attach method each time I restart the Appium server so I need to find a way to automate that.